# CGAL Nef_polyhedron compile error in bounding_box_3.h

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, cgal

I am attempting to create a simple test case for `Nef_Polyhedron` but keep running into a compile error even if there is only one line in the main function and I am not sure what to try next.

Below is my entire program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <CGAL/Polyhedron_3.h>
#include <CGAL/IO/Polyhedron_iostream.h>
#include <CGAL/Nef_polyhedron_3.h>
#include <CGAL/Exact_predicates_exact_constructions_kernel.h>

typedef CGAL::Exact_predicates_exact_constructions_kernel Kernel; 
typedef CGAL::Polyhedron_3<Kernel>  Polyhedron; 
typedef CGAL::Nef_polyhedron_3<Kernel> Nef_polyhedron; 

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    Nef_polyhedron N0;
}
```

The errors are as below:

```
Error   3   error C2039: 'hi' : is not a member of 'CGAL::Box_intersection_d::Box_d<double,3,CGAL::Box_intersection_d::ID_EXPLICIT>'    c:\program files\cgal-4.6.2\include\cgal\nef_3\bounding_box_3.h 91  1   CGAL_TEST
Error   1   error C2039: 'lo' : is not a member of 'CGAL::Box_intersection_d::Box_d<double,3,CGAL::Box_intersection_d::ID_EXPLICIT>'    c:\program files\cgal-4.6.2\include\cgal\nef_3\bounding_box_3.h 90  1   CGAL_TEST
Error   4   error C2065: 'hi' : undeclared identifier   c:\program files\cgal-4.6.2\include\cgal\nef_3\bounding_box_3.h 91  1   CGAL_TEST
Error   2   error C2065: 'lo' : undeclared identifier   c:\program files\cgal-4.6.2\include\cgal\nef_3\bounding_box_3.h 90  1   CGAL_TEST
```

The version of CGAL is 4.6.2.

Any suggestions?

Comment: The same code works for me. But try changing the kernel, as it helped me overcome this problem. Maybe in newer version more kernels are supported.